# Need to give read-write access to the .log file which is created by other windows user through VC++ application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

I have application in VC++. Which is creating test.log file when it launch and modify log file after session end of application.

My issue is Lets take two normal windows user test1 and test2 both do not have administrator rights.

1] when i login windfows using test1 user and launch my application. when application session end after 10 min if user do not make any operation. When application ends i am creating datalog.log file in "C:\ProgramData\MyApplication\datalog.log" location.

2] I logout windows test1 user

3]I login test2 user on same windows and run my application, This time when session ends, my application get crashed with error message as follows:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BEX   Application
>   Name: MyApplication.exe   Application Version:    1.0.0.0   Application
>   Timestamp:    5d60cf28   Fault Module Name:   ucrtbase.DLL   Fault Module
>   Version:  10.0.10240.16390   Fault Module Timestamp:  55a5bf73
>   Exception Offset: 0007c3b4   Exception Code:  c0000417   Exception
>   Data: 00000000   OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

To solve this i implemented following function

```
void SetFilePermission(LPCTSTR FileName)
{
    PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL;
    PACL pACL = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[1];
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;

    // Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
    AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
        SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pEveryoneSID);

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
    ZeroMemory(&ea, 1 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    ea[0].grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
    ea[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pEveryoneSID;

    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
    SetEntriesInAcl(1, ea, NULL, &pACL);

    // Initialize a security descriptor.  
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);

    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD,
        TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
        pACL,
        FALSE);   // not a default DACL 


                  //Change the security attributes
    SetFileSecurity(FileName, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD);

    if (pEveryoneSID)
        FreeSid(pEveryoneSID);
    if (pACL)
        LocalFree(pACL);
    if (pSD)
        LocalFree(pSD);
}
```

which is called from following

```
SetFilePermission(FileName); 
    stream = fopen( FileName, "a" );
    //LOG
    //fprintf( stream, "%s\n", s );
    fprintf( stream, "%s %s\n", buff, s );
    //LOG
    fclose( stream );
```

while debugging i application crashed without any message at `fprintf( stream, "%s %s\n", buff, s );` this line.

When i try to modify file manually it gives access rights permission message.

My need is to give read/writer access rights to the datalog.log file regardless of users login on windows and user who created the file.

Operating system is windows 7

Comment: 0xc0000417 is nasty, usually caused by UB induced by inadequate error checking.  None is visible in the snippets so not surprising.  The approach can't go anywhere, a default install of Windows does not have any folder that can be written to by multiple users.  Nor can a non-privileged user arbitrarily give itself write access.  Such a folder must be created at install time.

Comment: folder is created installed time only but datalog.log file is created/updated when session end